# Input/Output Warning and uncompression error during v.rast.stats processing

Tags: grass-gis, compression

First I use command `r.slope.aspect elevation=dem slope=dem_slope format=percent --overwrite` to calculate slopes in percent.
I get a warning during slope calculation: `WARNING: Unable to flush file fcell for raster map dem_slope: Input/output error`.
Then I use `v.rast.stats map=geodata_subbasins type=area raster=dem_slope column_prefix=slp method=average,stddev` to get average slope for zones from map geodata_subbasins and it's standard deviation. During execution I get errors:

```
WARNING: ZSTD compression error -20: Data corruption detected ERROR: Error uncompressing fp raster data for row 170 of <dem_slope>: error code -1
```

What could be the cause of warning and errors and what am I doing wrong here?
DEM is not corrupted, as it works with all r.stream and r.watershed commands properly. Memory problems are possible but not probable.

UPD: Adding `-e` flag helps. Resulting cell type is FCELL. So, it's not a problem with memory. Seem to be an issue with NODATA

UPD2: I think this question is related to [DCELL cell type is set automatically for raster after r.resamp.interp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/477643/dcell-cell-type-is-set-automatically-for-raster-after-r-resamp-interp) because both are issues of cell type setting.

Comment: What are your region settings (`g.region -p`)? How big is the dem (`r.info dem`)?  How much free disk space do you have?

Comment: As for disk space I have enough, I work with much smaller watershed now, which is a part of previous, and previous one was ok.
projection: 3 (Latitude-Longitude)
zone:       0
datum:      wgs84
ellipsoid:  wgs84
north:      60:02:39N
south:      54:18:39N
west:       119:18:51E
east:       124:31:15E
nsres:      0:00:03
ewres:      0:00:03
rows:       6880
cols:       6248
cells:      42986240
DEM: Type of Map:  raster   Data Type:    CELL, Rows:         18000, Columns:      12000, Total Cells:  216000000