# DCELL cell type is set automatically for raster after r.resamp.interp

Tags: grass-gis, interpolation, precision, pcraster

After interpolation with `r.resamp.interp` with bilinear method DCELL cell type is set for raster. When I export it with `r.out.gdal` I get a precision loss error, as I export it as Float32 (PCRaster driver).
Float64 isn't supported by this driver, also I don't need such big rasters with Float64 precision.

How can I set interpolation to get CELL or FCELL cell type, or how can I convert types after that?

r.resample command doesn't change cell type, but it also doesn't suit my task, because I have to change pixels resolution.

UPD: It does not depend on interpolation method, as nearest neighbour results in the same cell type.

UPD2: A possible solution could be r.mapcalc "raster = int(raster)" --overwrite It will convert all cells to CELL type. But this method isn't straightforward and beautiful. Also it brakes my int classes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be

```
r.resamp.interp input=raster output=new_raster method=nearest --overwrite
r.mapcalc "raster = int(raster)" --overwrite
```

Nearest neighbour won't generate various values on edges. r.mapcalc will convert all cells to CELL type. This is a solution, but isn't straightforward and beautiful.

Comment: Here you round to INTEGER (CELL) which is a major precision loss for your case. Better use the `float()` function for Float32 in `r.mapcalc`, then `r.out.gdal`. See also https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.mapcalc.html